# Pass value from JSP to SERVLET using URL

Tags: database, jsp, url, servlets, html-table

My goal is to pass value from jsp to servlet. I managed to pass the values of reservationId and tableId but NOT staffId.

The error was:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "staffId"

Why is that so? Is it because staffId is retrieve from DROPDOWN LIST?

Help will be appreciated!

```
<c:forEach items="${table}" var="table">
<tr>
<td>${table.reservationId}</td>
td><select name="staffId">
<c:forEach var="staff" items="${staff}">
<option value="${staff.staffId}">${staff.staffName}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</td>

<td>
<a href="TableEditServlet?action=assign&reservationId=<c:out value="${table.reservationId}"/>&tableId=<%= request.getParameter("tableId") %>&staffId=<c:out value="${staff.staffId}"/>">

<input value="Assign" class="btn"></a></td> </tr>

</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JavaScript` or `JQuery` to get data from `<select name="staffId" id="someId">` for the selected row.

**UPDATE**  (using javascript)

```
... add this javascript section before <body>
<script>
function assign(reservationId) {
document.location="TableEditServlet?action=assign&reservationId="+reservationId+"&staffId="+document.getElementById("staffId_"+reservationId).value;
// add tableId if you need as well
}
</script>
...
    <c:forEach items="${table}" var="table">
    <tr>
    <td>${table.reservationId}</td>
    <td>
    <select name="staffId" id="staffId_${table.reservationId}">
    <c:forEach var="staff" items="${staff}">
    <option value="${staff.staffId}">${staff.staffName}</option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input value="Assign" class="btn" onclick="assign('<c:out value="${table.reservationId}"/>')">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Is there any other way beside these 2 methods?

Comment: You want to submit staffId from the combobox chosen by user - it's client side, you cannot use JSTL `<c:out>` because it's server side programming.

Comment: However, the staffId is taken from database. That is why I used c:out to display in jsp

Comment: You have list of `staff` but trying to get one value `staff.staffId` somehow. `staff.staffId` is outside of your loop already.

Comment: Thanks. However is the code like this? Cant managed to do it :( input onclick="document.location='TableEditServlet?action=assign&reservationId=<c:out value="${table.reservationId}"/>&tableId=<%= request.getParameter("tableId") %>&staffId="+$("#staff").val();'"